# dynamic show more show less javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, dynamic, foreach

lets say i have 3 divs that has been **looped** i have div1 div2 div3 and for each div i have a button named "Show More", supposedly if i click the show more under div1 the details of div1 should appear, and if i clicked the show more under div2 the details of div2 should appear and if i clicked the show more in div3 the details of div3 should appear.

**The problem is this:** whenever i clicked show more under each div the details that will appear is div1. **how can i make the details of div2 appear if i clicked the show more under it and the details of div3 if i clicked the show more under it.**

example:

```
@foreach($detail as $detail)
   Title1: {{ $detail->detail1 }}
   Title2: {{ $detail->detail2 }}
   Title3: {{ $detail->detail3 }}
   <button class="btn btn-warning" data-target="#showthis" data-toggle="collapse">Show More</button>

   <div class="collapse" id="showthis">
      Title4: {{ $detail->detail4 }}
      Title5: {{ $detail->detail5 }}
      Title6: {{ $detail->detail6 }}
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
@foreach($detail as $detail)
<div class="content">
   Title1: {{ $detail->detail1 }}
   Title2: {{ $detail->detail2 }}
   Title3: {{ $detail->detail3 }}
   <button class="btn btn-warning show-more" data-target="#show" data-toggle="collapse">Show More</button>

   <div class="collapse" class="showthis">
      Title4: {{ $detail->detail4 }}
      Title5: {{ $detail->detail5 }}
      Title6: {{ $detail->detail6 }}
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

In javascript

```
$( ".showthis" ).hide();
$('.show-more').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.showthis').show();
});
```

Comment: that is in jquery, please give me a javascript format.